# How to auto adjust DIV height of Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Here is my demo on bootply

http://www.bootply.com/apMYKUW4mn

What I need is when left side having more content right side height should adjust automatically vice versa.

I am using bootstrap 3

Any ideas how to get rid of this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS flexbox like this to equalize the height of the cols..

http://www.bootply.com/POKBGzu0Ym